# Finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v=(3 ,1 ,3 ,-4)$ and $A=v^t\cdot v$.  Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ without calculating the whole matrix $A$

$Rank(AB) \leq min((Rank(A),Rank(B))$ so $Rank(A)\leq 1$ but because $A$ isn't the zero matrix $Rank(A)\neq 0$ and therefore $Rank(A)=1$.

$A$ is $4 \times 4$ size matrix so by rank-nullity theorem we get $4 = 1 + Null(A)$ $\rightarrow$ $Null(A)=3$ so $A$ is not invertible and $0$ is one of its eigenvalues.

How can I find the other eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: The nullity being 3 tells you more than just that $0$ is an eigenvalue....

Answer (score 4):

HINT: What happens if you compute $A \cdot v^t$?

Comment: $A\cdot v^t=v^t\cdot v\cdot v^t=0\cdot v^t$? So I need to look for $v^t\cdot v=0$?

Comment: No, $v \cdot v^t = \left\Vert v \right\Vert^2 = 35$, i.e. $A \cdot v^t = v^t \cdot 35 = 35 \cdot v^t$.